# Observation of an electric dipole moment for atoms

Tags: atoms, dipole-moment

Reading the answers to the question [How do we know neutrons have no charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504183/how-do-we-know-neutrons-have-no-charge) I started a search for the electric dipole moment of atoms.

About molecules ist is clear, in some molecules an electron comes under the influence of a neighbor atom and we observe an electric dipole. My search for atomic electric dipoles was not successful.

Was an electric dipole ever observed. if yes, I’m curious how such a measurement should be carried out in a way, not inducing such a moment from the measurement instrument.

Answer (score 0):

Atoms in an external electric field acquire an electric dipole moment. This explains the observed [Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect).

Comment: I’m curious how such a measurement should be carried out in a way, not inducing such a moment from the measurement instrument.